# how to import a json file with images exported from after efects to android studio?

Tags: android, json

I created an animation in after effects and I exported it to json but I exported it with some png images that I used in the animation and when I'm going to run them in android studio it does not read them and the animation does not work. Any idea that I read them or are all included in the .json file?

[image: esta es la carpeta assets]

Comment: is the .json files referring to relative paths or static paths?

Comment: The images are static

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lottie](https://airbnb.io/lottie/android/android.html#from-xml) to render this json.

Add dependency

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0"
    ...
}
```

Use in xml

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/hello_world"
    // or
    app:lottie_fileName="hello_world.json"

    // Loop indefinitely
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    // Start playing as soon as the animation is loaded
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, I already used the xml. The problem is that it runs the anumción obviating the png images of the file. I need that when I run the animation take the images and integrate them.

Comment: As per your comment what I understand is you want the animation on top of a image. So use a relative or any other layout you prefer and create an `LottieAnimationView` on top of a `ImageView` and set your png in the imageView